# How to calculate the width (in dots) of this zpl barcode?

Tags: barcode, zebra-printers, zpl

```
^XA
^FO0,90^AD^BY3
^BCN,100,Y,N,Y,A
^MD10
^FD1458622235534^FS
^XZ
```

Using [Label Viewer](http://labelary.com/viewer.html) I was able to play around with ZPL and after reading some documentation figured out that `^FO0,90` is what positions the barcode.  `0` is for the number of dots from the left and `90` is for the number of dots from the top.

My question is, how can the width of the above bar code be calcuated in dots?  If I know the width of the barcode, I can then center it programmatically.

The printer's resolution is 203dpi and given a 3' (width) x 2' (length) tag, that is 610 dots across.

What is the formula to calculate the width of a ZPL Barcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at the Code 128 wikipedia article for the details.

The natural unit of length for code 128 is the narrow bar width noted x (in your ZPL code set to 3 dots). A code 128 barcode (excluding the two 10x quiet zones) is made up of

1. a start character (11x wide)
2. n encoded character of width 11x
3. a CRC (11x wide)
4. a stop character (12x wide)

If your data takes n encoded characters, the length of the barcode is (34 + n*11)x. In your case, x is 3 dots, so at 8dot/mm the barcode will be (12.75 + n*4.125)mm wide.

You have to look into the encoding to figure out n. Minimal encodings are not unique, but in your case the data will be encoded with 8 barcode characters: 6 code C character (for 6 pairs of digits), 1 switch code character and 1 code A character (for the last digit). The barcode should be 45.75mm / 366dot wide.

There is a little issue with your ZPL. You specified a UCC checkcode on a non UCC barcode. I am not familiar with UCC/GS1-128 barcodes but that might introduce extra barcode characters or be irrelevant.

Also you might consider padding your timestamp with a leading 0. With Code 128, pairs of digit have a better encoding. A 14-digit barcode will be be 4.125mm shorter.

I just mentionned the quiet zone, barcode readers require them.

Answer (score 3):

The Code 128 barcode includes three modes.  The "A" in your ^BC means that the barcode algorithm will automatically select the best mode based on the placement of where the letters are mixed in with the numbers, and/or how many numbers are in a row.  This results in barcodes that vary in length depending on their content.

You can change that A to an N.  This will make the width easy to estimate, even if it's not the most space efficient.

For the N option: count 106 dots, total, for the bookends, and 33 dots for each digit.

For the N + Subset C option: If you can say for sure that you will always have an even number of digits (no letters, spaces, or other symbols).  You can force the barcode into subset C mode. Count 104 dots for the bookends, and 33 dots for every two digits.  But you must have an even number of digits.

```
^BCN,100,Y,N,Y,N
^FD>;1422335544^FS
```

The `>;` tells ZPL to render this as subset C.

If you know that you will need to support alphanumeric barcodes, then stick with the A.  This is where things get harder.

You will need to model the barcode algorithm in your programming language of choice.  Perhaps you could find an existing library, as Code 128 is a very popular barcode.  Use the library to render the barcode in memory.  You may have to play with the parameters to get it to produce a barcode equal to your ZPL output. Then have your program use the output of the library to determine the width of the barcode.

If your barcode is always going to be 13 digits, then automatic centering is a moot point.  The barcode will always be the same width, even in automatic mode.  Find the `^FO` that looks like it's centered on the label, and stick with that.  This barcode is 368 dots wide.  Try `^FO121,90`.

I didn't calculate the width of the barcode, I measured it by rendering the label to a Gif and then examining the label in a paint program that would let me count the dots.

Comment: Thank you. What is the ratio of dots to pixels?  For example the tag is 610 dots wide.

Comment: Also, the bar code is always going to be a plain 13 digit Unix time stamp.